# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая?

"Сдохну, как в сказке."

Answer (score 1):

1) **Сдохну, как в сказке.**

Нужна запятая, это сравнительный оборот, в устной речи делается пауза.

Также предложение можно также считать неполным сравнительным придаточным: **Сдохну так же, как герой  в сказке.**

2) Но оборот ***как в сказке*** может и не обособляться, если он входит в состав сказуемого или является обстоятельством: И это всё было **как в сказке**. Первое время мы жили в там **как в сказке** (= очень хорошо).